# What happens when you lose the virtual address of the page directory?

Tags: memory-management, x86, kernel, paging, osdev

I'm writing a memory manager for my kernel (32 bit x86)
In the course of this... I'm facing a bit of a dilemma....

**Description of virtual memory map:**

- Identity map of first 4 Mb
- Virtual address 0xC0000000 mapped to physical address 0x100000 (Also a 4 Mb map)

My page directory is at physical address 0x9c000.
My page table 1 is at physical address 0x9d000.
My page table 2 is at physical addres 0x9e000.

(I need only two page tables here :) ... These correspond to the identity map and higher memory map respectively)

Bless the identity mapping.... I can safely access my page directory and page tables as if paging wasn't even enabled. This makes it really easy for me to modify page tables,etc.

Now comes the issue: I may remove this identity mapping... If so, I can already imagine problems creeping up..
Eg. I have physical addresses that I want to access... But I can only access virtual ones. In order to map the virtual address to the required physical address, I need to access the page directory. But I have the physical address of the page directory... *I realize that I'm back where I started.

So, I'm guessing there's a need for some permanent mapping (or some sort of identity mapping for tables and the directory) so that I can forget about all this and get on with my life.

But if I map something permanently, I feel that I'm reducing the flexibilty of the program(kernel) in some sort of way.

What's the way one deals with this issue?

**What happens when you *lose* the virtual address of the page directory? You can always get the physical address from cr3, but you have no idea where it's mapped, how to access it, and whatnot. In this case, I don't think one can even change the page directory location using cr3 because you'd be loading a physical address into it, but all that you can view are virtual addresses... It seems like a really scary situation here**

Am I missing something?

Comment: Um, *don't* lose it!   You pretty much need to keep some chunk of memory mapped to known physical addresses, either identity or some known mapping (like high 2MiB maps to low 2MiB of physical).  You can make a whole new page directory tree and install it in CR3, but only if you have some known mapping somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes ... So you're kinda dead (I'd use a stronger word maybe ;) ) ...  If you lost the information (that was ultimately made by you - you define the mappings, etc.), it's crazy how you can't get it back from the processor :(

Comment: You could disable paging, except that doing that while CS:EIP isn't identity-mapped could be a problem to say the least.  Basically just don't write buggy kernels; it shouldn't be a shock that losing references to critical data is not recoverable.  It's not like the info is even there inside the CPU somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes... That's true! I was just amazed at how badly you can mess up with such a simple issue... Also, would you advise keeping a permanent identity map? (4M)

Comment: @PeterCordes While the processor doesn't have the info, it can access physical addresses (the MMU can)... Well, we'd be safe if there was some way to force use physical addresses, but this is just wishful thinking... :)

Comment: Linux's design seems good; it 1:1 direct maps all of physical memory (except for high memory on 32-bit machines).  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt.  Not *identity*, but with a known mapping.  It *also* maps some of those physical pages to other virtual addresses.  Having lots of virtual address space is very useful, and is why PAE (large phys addresses with 32-bit virtual) was so hard to use.   https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/ quotes some Linus Torvalds ranting about it: fun and informative :)

Comment: Yes that's true, Intel could have provided a special store instruction that uses a register as a physical address instead of virtual.  But opcode space is very limited, and 386 would have had to support decoding an extra instruction just for that super-rare use-case that would only benefit a couple instructions executed per several thousand at best.  And if you use it blindly, you might be overwriting your own code or stack.  An OS has to know physical addresses anyway to program DMA hardware, and then will want efficient reads of the data via normal virtual address...

Comment: @PeterCordes Cool stuff!

Comment: In 64-bit it is just easier to map all of physical memory space at high virtual memory address. On 32-bit systems you can't really do that. Some 32-bit kernels may map a portion of memory for dealing with paging structures, but some people are also known to use the **recursive page tables technique** (you can google them). They are more complicated to understand and they do take up some of the virtual address space (particularly bad if you use PAE in protected mode), and the solution isn't portable to other CPU architectures.

Comment: One complication with rescurive page tables is that you can't easily alter the structures of another process and it usually involves some for of temporary page mapping but it is doable despite the extra complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't lose your virtual Page directory address! You need at least a small portion of the page directory at a know physical and a known virtual address (they do not need identity mapped).