# Problems removing identity mapping in x86 kernel

Tags: memory-management, x86, kernel, paging, osdev

I'm doing a bit of operating system development and here's my target. I've enabled paging and want to remove the identity mapping. Previously, I had two mappings, identity map of 0-4M and kernel at virtual address 0xC0000000 mapped to physical address 1M. My bootloader does this before the jump to the kernel and it's the kernel's responsibility to remove the identity map. My stack pointer has value 0x90000 now. My strategy is as follows:

After I enter the kernel, I use recursive page tables to have access (I get their virtual addresses: [What happens when you lose the virtual address of the page directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228298/what-happens-when-you-lose-the-virtual-address-of-the-page-directory)) to my page directory and all other page tables. Recursive page tables: The last entry of the page directory points to itself.

I want to remap the stack and give it a virtual address. Since 0xFFC00000-0xFFFFFFFF are used by the recursive page technique, I use 0xFFC00000 as the virtual address of the stack, which I map to 0x90000 physical.

I then re-initialize the gdt.

Now the state of my system is this:

```
(qemu) info registers 
EAX=000241a0 EBX=c00019de ECX=00000001 EDX=000241a0
ESI=00008137 EDI=00103800 EBP=ffc00000 ESP=ffc00000
EIP=c00019de EFL=00000087 [--S--PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     c0004100 00000027
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=80000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=0009c000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

stack remapping code:

```
STACK equ 0xFFC00000
STACK_PHY equ 0x90000

global refresh_stack ;A solution for switching stacks

refresh_stack:
    mov ebx,[esp] ;Return address
    mov esp,STACK
    mov ebp,STACK
    jmp ebx
```

I want to remove identity mapping as such:

```
void remove_identity_map()  //This would remove the 4M identity map
{
         if (entry_is_present(_page_directory[0]))
                _page_directory[0] = 0;  //Unmapping the whole of 4M

         flush_tlb();
}
```

Where flush_tlb:

```
flush_tlb:
    mov eax,cr3
    mov cr3,eax
    ret
```

A minimal reproducible example (roughly)

```
void kmain()
{
set_recursive_map();
refresh_stack();
install_gdt(); //The standard 4 entries Data/Code * User/kernel
remove_identity_map();
   .......
   .......
}
```

The place it goes wrong is when I flush_tlb(). If I comment out that line, the code works as expected, but we would be seeing cached copies. However, when I keep it, the system(emulator) restarts from BIOS! (Triple fault???)

Also, I'm using qemu, and after I flush tlb, I've tried `for(;;);` to use the qemu-monitor to `info tlb`... It doesn't seem to be flushed. All the entries from before are present..

Where could I be going wrong?

Note: When I was debugging (single-stepping) with gdb, access to address 0xFFC00000 was **not** possible after I'd flushed the tlb... But that does make sense, I just deleted the page directory entry corresponding to page table 0..

Update: One remapping I haven't done is of video memory! For text mode I'm still accessing 0xB8000. Since my exception handler also prints to screen, this is a sure source of triple fault!!!

Comment: *the system(emulator) restarts from BIOS!*  Have you tried using a debugger to see what fault makes that happen?  Is it in an instruction right after `invlpg` or `mov cr3,eax`?  Is there a page fault, and a double fault trying to deliver that fault from an invalid stack?  Thus leading to triple fault

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not using invlpg here.. it's a full refresh. Also qemu isn't refreshing it, i.e. info tlb isn't changing after flush_tlb

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have exception handlers which are basically for(;;); preceded by a display of the exception name

Comment: An exception handler can't run if you triple fault because of an invalid stack address, exactly like I described.  That's why you should use a debugger.  e.g. BOCHS has a built-in debugger that I assume would tell you if the machine triple faulted, or just single-stepping past the `mov` to CR3 in your current setup should tell you something if it resets on one of the instructions soon after that.  Your question doesn't appear to show which instruction faulted so that's not a very good [mcve].  If you do know which instruction is a problem, put that in the question.  If not, find out.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure! However, I'm positive that the function flush_tlb() as a whole gets executed I think... Why? Because a for (;;); after that does get executed.

Comment: Ok, that rules out breaking the stack if `ret` still works.  But seeing which instruction specifically faults would be a good idea.  If it's a memory access, you can look at the address for clues.  And if your fault handlers aren't printing anything, you can look at why not: never reached or did they fail.  Although maybe the 0xFFC00000 not accessible is already enough of a clue; Did you look at the relevant page-table entries for it yourself to make sure they were still good and marked "present"?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem but you say you have exception handlers. Are you sure they work? I ask because I see `IDT=     00000000 000003ff`. That is often the location and size of the real mode IVT. Now it may be that you placed your IDT right on top of the old realmode IVT - but I am asking - is that what you did? If you didn't then there is something amiss with your IDTR/IDT.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `refresh_stack` uses a non-volatile register EBX. EBX needs to be saved and restored by the function per the 32-bit x86 CDECL calling convention. Any reason you didn't use a volatile register like EAX? As well you do `jmp ebx` that jumps back to the return address but what happens if the caller used the stack and there were variables/data on it? Your `refresh_stack` function is very  fragile.

Comment: It looks like  IDT base is still 0, so any interrupt or fault of any kind is going to triple fault, unless you have added a mapping for that. Are interrupts disabled?

Comment: @prl : `EFL=00000087` indicate interrupts (IF) are off (Bit 9 is 0)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, Yes, refresh_stack is very fragile. However, it seems to be a really simple way of just 'resetting' the stack to whatever position I want. I would love to hear anything other ways to do that. Also, using ebx was an arbitrary choice, I should probably change that

Comment: A fancy thing you can do with qemu (or even more easily, bochs) is build it yourself, then run it under a debugger, so rather than debugging your kernel, you are debugging qemu, a sort of virtual in-circuit-emulator if you like.   You just have to figure out where the code to handle "load %cr3" is in qemu, set a breakpoint there, run your kernel, and the second time it hits, single step until you see qemu go haywire.  Easy game :)

Comment: @mevets: Is that really more useful that connecting to QEMU as a GDB-remote?  Or using BOCH's built-in debugger which can also basically debug the guest machine.  This lets you see fault reasons, even when they would make a pure in-guest kernel debugger unusable, like interrupts disabled or exception handlers broken.  For this case specifically, it should be easy to see page fault addresses and identify any virtual addresses still using the unmapped memory.

Comment: Yes, you get to step through the emulation of the opcode, which points out problems way faster than interpreting fault codes -- 0 only has so many interpretations.   In the OPs case, it is resetting/shutting down [ the idt is uninitialized, pointing at 0 which is being unmapped ].   Bochs, desepite being C++, is way easier to follow than qemu, the latter being a more general system with more abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like I forgot to remap video memory! I was still accessing 0xb8000 for VGA text mode. The reason for the question was that I hadn't identified this access below 1M. If I had, I wouldn't have asked a question ;).

Therefore this can be a good lesson for people looking to remove their identity map after they enable paging:

- Remap gdt
- Remap idt
- Remap stack
- Remap video_memory